# Excel MySQL - multiple computers

Tags: excel

I have setup MySql For Excel and can connect to the databses on my website so can import tables into Excel.  If I open the Excel file on another computer it does not recognise the connection.  I can setup a new connection (which is what it prompts me to do) but then it breaks if I revert to open the save file on the original computer.  I seem to be stuck with each connection being fixed to an individual computer.

How can I relosve this as I want to open the same Excel file on multiple computers and for the connection to be working?

Comment: Look does it is possible to use DSN? if so then use it - it is specific for workstation or for user account on the workstation.

Comment: Connections are created on the local computer and cannot be shared with other computers. Having the same connection name may help.

Comment: That's a shame.  I have tried the same conenction name but it does not like it.

Comment: Do you need updating of data from excel or only reporting? If the latter, then using myodbc (still need to install it on all machines) with a connection string may be a better solution than mysql for exel. If you need updating of data, then it is not a great solution (you can make it work, but you need to do the dev work in VBA).

Comment: Thanks, that works.  As long as the ODBC connect has exactly the same details on all computers that I can open the same Excel doc on each computer and refresh the table.